# ng-selected and selecting default option

Tags: angularjs

I am using the following code to display default option upon scope var newclient = true, newclient is set to true / false by the link shown below. Unfortunately ng-selected is not selecting the option as default option when newclient is true. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here and how to fix it? Thanks

```
    <select ng-disabled="newclient" name="clients" id="clients">
        <option value="0">
          Select Client...
        </option>
        <option ng-selected="newclient" value="1">
          Create New Client
        </option>
      </select>

     <a href="" ng-click="newclient = !newclient"></a>
```

Comment: Pheraps because when newclient is true, the whole select is disabled? (from your code: `select ng-disabled="newclient"`...)

Comment: Works for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/5SaOSXH0EASvJiRDSOZR?p=preview

Comment: @MarcoS tried removing ng-disabled nothing changed, same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something ('TOGGLE-ME', for example), in a href link text, to make it clickable... When you click it, it works, for me:

```
     <select ng-disabled-REMOVED="newclient" name="clients" id="clients">
        <option value="0">
          Select Client...
        </option>
        <option ng-selected="newclient" value="1">
          Create New Client
        </option>
      </select>

     <a href="" ng-click="newclient = !newclient">TOGGLE-ME</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, obviously it works well outside my app...Is it possible that the select related CSS classes have anything to do with this problem? I mean I doubt CSS could have anything to do with this, but just wondering